# scrape date in Q&A forum

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

In this thread

https://www.healthboards.com/boards/aspergers-syndrome/949512-im-lost.html

I'm trying to find the date of each post

I could find this

```
css="td.thead:first-child"
```

So when I run this

```
html_text(html_nodes(read_html("https://www.healthboards.com/boards/aspergers-syndrome/949512-im-lost.html"), css="td.thead:first-child"))
```

I get the dates

```
[1] "  \r\n\t\t\t05-13-2013, 11:06 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "Sponsors "                                    "  \r\n\t\t\t07-26-2013, 08:15 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t "
 [4] "  \r\n\t\t\t04-26-2014, 06:28 PM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "  \r\n\t\t\t05-07-2014, 02:43 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "  \r\n\t\t\t09-19-2014, 07:28 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t "
 [7] "  \r\n\t\t\t09-19-2014, 07:29 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "Thread Tools"                                 " \r\n\t\tPosting Rules\r\n\t"                   
[10] "LinkBack"                                     "Bookmark & Share"
```

I get the dates but also "Thread tools", "Posting Rules" and "Bookmark & Share".. what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the CSS style you are using to match the dates can also be found elsewhere on the page, thus returning those other entries. You can use a [CSS Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to only look inside tables that have an ID beginning with 'post'. The selector is `table[id^='post']` and the full solution would be:

```r
html_text(html_nodes(read_html("https://www.healthboards.com/boards/aspergers-syndrome/949512-im-lost.html"), css="table[id^='post'] td.thead:first-child"))

[1] "  \r\n\t\t\t05-13-2013, 11:06 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "  \r\n\t\t\t07-26-2013, 08:15 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t "
[3] "  \r\n\t\t\t04-26-2014, 06:28 PM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "  \r\n\t\t\t05-07-2014, 02:43 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t "
[5] "  \r\n\t\t\t09-19-2014, 07:28 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t " "  \r\n\t\t\t09-19-2014, 07:29 AM\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t "
```